# Rearrange cells in tableview during runtime

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

Could someone please point me in the right direction on how to allow the cells to be able to move in a `UITableView`?

At the moment when I click and hold and then drag below the second cell it doesn't move. It just drags all the cells with it and stretches back up again.

I would like to be able to move the cells so I can basically rearrange the cells during runtime. can someone please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is functionality that the `UITableView` provides for you.

Check the [Managing the Reordering of Rows](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH11-SW1) section in the [TableView Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can only rearrange tableview cells when in edit mode.

look for this line of code within your program :

```
// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

It should be commented if you haven't touched it yet.

cheers !

Kyle

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath 
       toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
```